# Prove that $\frac{1}{[Z^{-1}]_{kk}}=\frac{\text{det}Z} {\text{det}Z_{kk}}=\text{det}Z_{kk}^{\text{SC}}$, $Z_{kk}^{\text{SC}}$ is the Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Suppose $Z$ is a complex (Wishart) matrix. Let $a=\frac{1}{[Z^{-1}]_{kk}}$, where $Z^{-1}$ is the inverse of $Z$ and $[Z^{-1}]_{kk}$ represents the $(k,k)$-th entry of $Z^{-1}$.

When I was reading an article, I saw that they define $Z_{kk}^{\text{SC}}$ as the *Schur complement* of $Z_{kk}$, and they claim that 
$a=\frac{\text{det}Z} {\text{det}Z_{kk}}=\text{det}Z_{kk}^{\text{SC}}$.

Could you please tell me what does the Schur complement mean? and how I can prove the above claim ?